# Simple inequality with unknown in the exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $0<\alpha\ll1$ I have the following inequality:
$$
2\alpha^2x\geq \alpha^{2x}
$$
It looks trivial, but I wasn't able to find the $x$ that verify the condition. Anyone any clue?

Comment: $x=1$ gives you $2\alpha ^2 \ge \alpha ^2$ which is always true for $\alpha < 1$.

Comment: Are you looking for the set of all possible $x$?

Comment: x=1/2, $\alpha^2<\alpha$,now you should be able find x range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general approach.
Let $$f(x) = \alpha^{2x} \text{ and } g(x) = 2 \alpha^2 x,$$ 
then $$f'(x) = 2\log(\alpha) \alpha^{2x} \text{ and } g'(x) = 2 \alpha^2.$$

Note that $f$ is always decreasing and $g$ is always increasing. When $x = 1$ we have $g(x) > f(x)$, and hence the inequality holds (in particular) for all $x \geq 1$.

Comment: err it is quite possible i have misinterpreted the question